# Retornar Lista em uma View

Tags: c#, mvc

Olá, eu sou um iniciando em C# e MVC e estou tendo dificuldades em retornar uma lista de dados. Tenho o código abaixo e não sei como fazer pra retornar os dados carregados da lista. Alguém pode me sugerir como fazer isso? 
Obrigado

```
  public class EstoqueAcabadoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: EstoqueAcabado
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            using (BD context = new BD())
            {
                var query = from c in context.V500_ESTOQUE_ACAB select c;
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    ViewBag.cod_deposito = item.COD_DEPOSITO;
                    ViewBag.cod_reduzido = item.COD_REDUZIDO;
                    ViewBag.desc_cor =     item.DESC_COR;
                    ViewBag.desc_artigo =  item.DESC_ARTIGO;
                    ViewBag.peso_peca =    item.PESO_PECA;
                }
                return ();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Velho eu não entendi direito qual o objeto que você quer passar como lista, mas o que eu fiz ai foi:

Criei uma lista de `V500_ESTOQUE_ACAB`

```
List<V500_ESTOQUE_ACAB> estoque = new List<V500_ESTOQUE_ACAB>();
```

Depois continuei na iteração dos objetos dentro da query e fui adicionando os objetos na lista:

```
estoque.add(new estoque(){
                COD_DEPOSITO = item.COD_DEPOSITO,
                COD_REDUZIDO = item.COD_REDUZIDO,
                DESC_COR = item.DESC_COR,
                DESC_ARTIGO = item.DESC_ARTIGO,
                PESO_PECA = item.PESO_PECA
            });
```

E depois adicionei a `List<V500_ESTOQUE_ACAB>` na ViewBag:

```
public class EstoqueAcabadoController : Controller
{
    // GET: EstoqueAcabado
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        List<V500_ESTOQUE_ACAB> estoque = new List<V500_ESTOQUE_ACAB>();
        using (BD context = new BD())
        {
            var query = from c in context.V500_ESTOQUE_ACAB select c;
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                estoque.add(new estoque(){
                    COD_DEPOSITO = item.COD_DEPOSITO,
                    COD_REDUZIDO = item.COD_REDUZIDO,
                    DESC_COR = item.DESC_COR,
                    DESC_ARTIGO = item.DESC_ARTIGO,
                    PESO_PECA = item.PESO_PECA
                });
            }
            ViewBag.estoque = estoque;
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Dentro da sua View você vai importar esse objeto assim:

```
List<V500_ESTOQUE_ACAB> estoque = (List<V500_ESTOQUE_ACAB>)ViewBag.estoque;
```

Edit:Se NÃO FOR ESSE O OBJETIVO DA PERGUNTA, COMENTA QUE EU AJUSTO E A GENTE RESOLVE ISSO

Comment: Na verdade, eu to aprendendo o MVC. Então, eu fiz uma maneira pra pegar uma coluna só da minha tabela, pra jogar lá no view e funcionou. Agora, quero pegar todas as colunas da minha tabela (que é o objeto query) para jogar lá na view. Entendeu ? Acho que é uma lista né, que preciso fazer. Obrigado!!

Comment: Ahhh Cleiton, você quer tipo colocar tudo em um lugar só ?

Comment: @CleitondeLimas eu recomendo você criar um objeto com as variáveis que vocÊ quer e passar o objeto ao todo. Seria isso ?

Comment: Quero por exemplo, "carregar" o resultado do meu select (com todas as colunas) para mostrar tudo na view, entendeu?

Comment: @CleitondeLimas ok entendi, me explica uma coisa... `V500_ESTOQUE_ACAB` é um objeto com os atributos: `COD_DEPOSITO`, `COD_REDUZIDO`,`DESC_COR`,`DESC_ARTIGO` e `PESO_PECA` certo

Comment: na verdade, o v500_estoque_acab é a tabela do meu banco de dados, e nela constam 30 colunas. O que eu quero é como se fosse trazer todos as colunas desta tabela, e jogar como o return do controller, pra poder ser acesso na minha view e listar o resultrado da query.